# Counting cell value changes in table - Excle or VBA

Tags: vba, excel-formula

I have weekly stored credit ratings in a table, each row representing a historical rating, and each column representing that rating for an individual company.

```
column A  Column B  Column C
AA-       BBB-      AA-
AA        BBB-      AA-
AA        BBB       AA-
AA        BBB       BBB+
AA-       BBB       BBB+
```

The goal is to count the number of upgrades (For instance from AA- to AA) and downgrades (from BBB to BBB-) for the entire table. I am not really sure where to start, but I am familiar to VBA and would be grateful for any suggestions on how to accomplish this.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd step through each column then each row within that column, accumulating the number of increases and decreases.

(Assuming you've no headers)

```
sequence = array("BBB", "BBB+", "A-", "A", "A+", "AA-", "AA", "AA+", "AAA")  'You get the idea, lowest first, highest last, fill out as necessary

iCol = 1
Do until isempty(Cells(1,iCol))  'Looping through each company

    nIncrease = 0  'Counter for number of increases for this company
    nDecrease = 0  

    iRow = 2  'Start at row 2 (as we'll start by checking relative to row 1)
    do until isempty(Cells(iRow, iCol))  'Looping through each row
         prevRating =Cells(iRow-1, iCol) 
         currRating =Cells(iRow, iCol) 
         iPrev = worksheetfunction.match(prevRating, sequence,0)
         iCurr = worksheetfunction.match(currRating , sequence,0)
         'You could easily nest Cells(iRow-1, iCol) in to the iPrev line (and same for iCurr) - just keeping it separate so you can follow steps more easily
          
         if iPrev > iCurr then
             'Downgrade
             nDecrease = nDecrease + 1
         elseif iCurr > iPrev then
              'Upgrade
             nIncrease = nIncrease + 1
         else
             'Will be same rating, no change - just including this here for completeness of explanation, delete "else" from your code as its nonsensical
         end if

         iRow  = iRow + 1
    Loop

    'After gather information on the company, present it somewhere, here just firing it in 5 rows below:        
     Cells(iRow+5, iCol) = nIncrease
     Cells(iRow+6, iCol) = nDecrease
     

    iCol = iCol + 1
Loop
```

Obviously, then, if you wanted to check across the board for nIncrease & nDecrease, you'd do a summation on the two rows you dumped nIncrease & nDecrease into for each company.